# Insertion Sort - for loop in Java

Tags: java, loops, sorting, insertion

I am working with this insertion sort for loop and I am trying to wrap my head around it

```
    int[] number = {34, 56, 76, 12, 4, 70, 47};

    for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
            int j = i - 1;
            int point = number[i];
            while (j >= 0 && number[j] > point) {
                number[j + 1] = number[j];
                j = j-1;
            }
            number[ j + 1] = point;
```

why do we need to use the

```
            int j = i - 1;
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: To prevent `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` in this line `number[j + 1] = number[j];`

Comment: Because with `int j = i;` on the first step `number[i]` and `number[j]` would reference the same index, which is kind of pointless (why compare the number at index i to itself?)